# How to write the query in postgres in which i have to join two tables with specific condition?

Tags: postgresql-10

I have to build a query the example fiddle is given [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7a1c9a5928f322238e73c3f3e97a3df0).

In this ctx.params.user_id Is a variable

The conditions which i have to satisfy is as follows.

If the value in effective_employee_type = ALL or the value in effective_employee_type = SPECEFIC and the column value in user table is has the id which is present in f.effective_employees Then it has to return the flash_message Same is applicable for all other columns as well which i have shown on the condition. And if the value in f.effective_employee_type = Except And the us.id is present in f.effective_employees then the message should not show. Same for all other columns as well

```
Show the message If employee_id present or type == ALL or
  SPECIFIC, if the value is except DONT fetch the message, 
Show the message If depat_id    present or type == ALL or
  SPECIFIC, if the value is except DONT fetch the message, 
Show the message If desig_id   present or type == ALL or
  SPECIFIC, if the value is except DONT fetch the message, 
Show the message If grade_id   present or type == ALL or
  SPECIFIC, if the value is except DONT fetch the message,
```

The query which I have written is as follows but this is not working how can i solve this?

```
SELECT 
  f.effective_department_type, 
  f.effective_designation_typeflash.effective_grade_type, 
  f.id, 
  f.tenant_id, 
  f.user_message, 
  f.user_id, 
  f.doc_path, 
  f.type_message, 
  f.type_emp_choose 
FROM org.flash_message f 
INNER JOIN org.users us ON (f.user_id = us.id) 
WHERE us.id::text = 
    ANY(string_to_array(translate(f.effective_employees,'[]',''), ',')) 
AND (f.effective_department_type = 'ALL'
OR f.effective_designation_type = 'ALL'
OR f.effective_grade_type = 'ALL'
OR us.department_id::text = 
    ANY(string_to_array(translate(f.effective_departments,'[]',''), ','))
OR us.designation_id::text = ANY(string_to_array(translate(f.effective_designations,'[]',''), ','))
OR us.grade_id::text = ANY(string_to_array(translate(f.effective_grades,'[]',''), ',')))
AND f.is_archived = 'false'
AND us.id =${ctx.params.user_id}`;
```

Comment: I tried to tidy up this query - I don't know what ` f.effective_designation_typeflash.effective_grade_type` means - you might want to add/change some of what I"ve done. Use aliases where possible - makes things much more legible - and put separate fields on separate lines - and put spaces between fields. Finally, 9.6 is now unsupported - you should upgrade!

Comment: I am using 10 + But in fiddle there only i could choose upto 9.6 And the types will be SPECEFIC,ALL,EXCEPT (Specefic means only to that particular departments All means effective to all the departments Except means except that particular department)

Comment: Use dbfiddle.uk - much better fiddle! Put any additional information in with the question!

Comment: Here is the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f9ca5222fffa73c9f440bc3cde06d96a I also changed the version as well.

Comment: Put that in the question!

Comment: Edited the question above.

Comment: Please put your (working) query into the fiddle that I put into the question!

Comment: Added the same and updated the link above

Comment: You didn't even **try** to run your query! How do you expect us to tidy this up? [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=64d5a95249eb9fc00b9a72f3c2ede855) is a "working" query (well, it runs at least) which returns no results! This ` ${ctx.params.user_id}` is some sort of progamming construct (PHP?) and won't work in a fiddle!

Comment: Edited here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c1af7350fc38f09c503dff31ff884a28 this is a variable ` ${ctx.params.user_id}` Which will change In new fiddle i have made it as 1

Comment: "Show the message If employee_id present or type == ALL or SPECIFIC, if the value is except DONT fetch the message,"   Would it be possible to rephrase this, to make the logic understandable?

Comment: if the value in effective_employee_type = ALL or the value in effective_employee_type = SPECEFIC and the column value in user table is has the id which is present in f.effective_employees Then it has to return the flash_message Same is applicable for all other columns as well which i have shown on the condition.  And if the value in f.effective_employee_type = Except And the us.id is present in f.effective_employees then the message should not show. Same for all other columns as well.

Comment: Also attaching a table to understand the logic along with this https://ethercalc.net/dqxcvx3lzg2f